Creating Branches in VSCode get associated with my GitHub Account, but Commits don´t
when I create a branch in VSCode via "git checkout -b test" a new branch is created on Github and its shown as "My Branch". So there is a connection between my VSCode and GitHub. I also have set the params name and email correctly. However when I am commiting something the association to my Account isnt there. As you can see in the Pictues. Any Idea how I can fix this?enter image description here
The Account-Name is Correct but it is not clickable, there is no connection to my actual Account
Yet I am signed in through VSCode
As you can see the Username is the same, but the account isnt connected
Checking the git config
Changing the Email to my second Account Email
